# How do I set global variable original values without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I set global variable default values

I have 200 global variables in my whole project and I need to reset all variables to original value same as we set in load time without refreshing my application page. These 200 global variable spread across 200 files and also we have created some variables inside functions so I can not able to store default values to reset. Any funtion or any windows object where I get default values
Eg: This is just an example

```
Text="Testig";
X="100";
Y="200";
```

In my different files these values will get changed  say

```
 Text="Testing-1";
 X="101";
 Y="201";
```

I need to reset these modified values

Comment: Just set a second pair of variables to the original value

Comment: No, I can not. I have already developed code and these global variables are spread in 200 files

Comment: Okay, what have you tried then? And, do you know the values, or are they (semi-)random?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var Text,X,Y;

function set_default(){
   Text="Testig";
   X="100";
   Y="200"
}

 set_default();

 Text="Testing-1";
 X="101";
 Y="201";

 console.log(Text,X,Y);
 set_default();
 console.log(Text,X,Y);
```

**UPDATE:**

You can write one universal function to check the availability of global variables. And when available then, assign them default values.
Like this:

```js
var test,X,Y,xxx;

function set_global_default(){
   for(var key in window){
     switch(key){
        case 'test':              /* global variable name */
            window[key]="Testig"; /* global variable value */
            break;
        case 'X':
            window[key]="100";
            break;
        case 'Y':
            window[key]="200";
            break;
        case 'xxx':
            window[key]="000";
            break;
        case 'abc':
            window[key]="abc";
            break;
        /* ...more... */                
       }
   }
}

 set_global_default();

 test="Testing-1";
 X="101";
 Y="201";
 xxx="xxx";

 console.log(test,X,Y,xxx);
 set_global_default();
 console.log(test,X,Y,xxx);
```

Comment: No,I can not set Default values, because my variables are spread over 200 files

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to store the variables as an object, e.g.

```
var defaultValues = {
   text: "Testig",
   x: 100,
   y: 200
}
var data = defaultValues;
```

You can work with the `data` variable, e.g.

```
data.text = "My new text";
alert(data.text);
```

And the moment you like to replace all current data by the default values, you just have to do one assignment, e.g., on a click event:

```
<button onclick="javascript: data=defaultValues;">
```

So you avoid to re-assign all variables individually.